# jQuery и сайт на Opencart

Tags: jquery, opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На одной кнопке 2 события навешаны при клике, при чем они одинаковые. Как мне найти первой событие что "главная страница:450" и отредактировать?
в индекс.php нету ничего

Comment: 450 здесь это номер строчки, смотреть надо исходный код в строке 450, а не index.php. Так же по всему проекту поиск можно сделать по запросу `#menu-icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используешь Chrome, то

1. F12
2. Elements - справа будет Event Listeners
3. Находишь свое событие (click, blur etc)
4. Находишь свой элемент и по строчке определяешь событие